# VSTS release to azure succeeded but url doesn't work

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a simple MVC application. In VSTS, build is success and release to Azure WebApp is also success. But azure url doesn't work. Application runs & works in local. Azure WebApp also looks good. Not sure if its issue with Azure or VSTS Release pipeline. IS Azure WebApp capable of running MVC applications?

My VSTS release pipe-line:

[image: VSTS CD Pipe-line]

Comment: Did you try VSTS new CD screen - Options might have changes

Comment: Have you logged into the scm site to see if the files you expect are actually on the server? If your Azure WebApp URL is xxx.azurewebsites.net, find your scm site by going to xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net. Then choose Debug Console -> CMD from the top menu to browse the files on your WebApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the MVC application (MVC template project in Visual Studio) can be run on Azure Web App.

Secondly, the App Service URL option of **Azure App Service Deploy** task Provide a name, like `FabrikamWebAppURL` for the variable for the AzureRM Web App Hosted URL. The variable can be used as `$(variableName)`, like `$(FabrikamWebAppURL)` to refer to the Hosted URL of the AzureRM Web App in subsequent tasks, such as **PowerShell**.

Thirdly, you can refer to these steps below to build and deploy application:

1. NuGet Tool Installer (Version of NuGet.exe to install: 4.3.0)
2. NuGet restore
3. Visual Studio Build (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"`)
4. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to publish: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`)
5. Create a new release definition
6. Azure App Service Deploy (Package or folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Release pipeline for better understanding

Comment: Do we have any chance in VSTS to configure release through PublishSettings file. 
I got the PublishSettings file downloaded from Publish profile option in WebApp from azure. If possible, it would be great

Comment: @AdityaPrasad Which points you don't understanding? Yes: 1. Right click the project=>Publish=>Import=>Select PublishSettings file=>Add .pubxml and pubxml.user files to source control 2. Change MSBuild argument: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[publish profile name]"

Comment: Could you please elobrate on Step 6.

Comment: Kindly check with my Release pipeline step - Screenshot attached

Comment: I am not clear about what you mean? Regarding step 6, you need to check Publish using web deploy option in Additional Deployment options section.